# Can I trigger an event when Azure AD is synchronized?

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

We are working on an automation program and I need to know if the Azure AD is synchronized (using code) before proceeding to the next task.

I know we can check for USN for replication but I would like to stay away from checking for the replication of a property because there are many records being processed, the synchronization to Azure AD happens every 30 minutes so that is a long time and forcing synchronization is a no-go as it would cause other problems.

Is there an API for Azure AD Connect to check the last successful synchronization from on-prem AD to Azure AD or something that triggers an event that I can use to automate tasks that need to happen after this synchronization? Any alternative ideas?

There is no code to show as I don't have problems with the code. I need some guidance on what are the best options and if there is anything available out there that I can use but I'm not finding.

Comment: Did you figure something out? I am polling the "Users" endpoint of the graph Api to do that...

Comment: I didn't figure that straightforward way. A workaround is building an automation service that runs every X minutes and then checks the synchronization. You can use that to trigger another service or run your tasks.